# Color rectangle one by one in a canvas

Tags: html, for-loop, canvas, settimeout, jss

I have canvas on which there are number of rectangle drawn so that the make a grid. What I want is to color each rectangle one by one in the grid until each of them are colored black and then again select few of them to color white in the same way one by one. I have tried few methods using "for" loop and "setTimeout" but its not working out.
I have recently started javascript that's why I need help to do this.

This code only includes the making of the grid no further because that part was not working out:

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

tileW = 20;
tileH = 20;

tileRowCount = 25;
tileColCount = 40;

var tile = [];

for (c = 0; c < tileColCount; c++) {
  tile[c] = [];
  for (r = 0; r < tileRowCount; r++){
    tile[c][r] = {
      x: c * (tileW + 3),
      y: r * (tileH + 3),
      state: 'e'
    }; //state e for empty
  }
}

for (c = 0; c < tileColCount; c++)
  for (r = 0; r < tileRowCount; r++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#AAAAAA';
    ctx.rect(tile[c][r].x, tile[c][r].y, tileW, tileH);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width='1000' height='600'></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='data.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. You're missing a `{` after this line `for (c = 0; c < tileColCount; c++)`

Comment: Sorry that must have happened when I was pasting the code that I wrote on my editor. But the problem is not that it's coloring the rectangles one by one using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Update your rendering code to use the `fillRect` method from the 2d context.

Replace this:

```js
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#AAAAAA';
ctx.rect(tile[c][r].x, tile[c][r].y, tileW, tileH);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

With this:

```js
ctx.fillStyle = "#AAAAAA";
ctx.fillRect(tile[c][r].x, tile[c][r].y, tileW, tileH);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want. My guess is that you want a checkerboard. The following will do so.

### The [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator

The operator [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) returns the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) after division. eg `3 % 2` is 1 and `4 % 2` is 0

We can use the remainder operator to let us know which color to make each square. As we count down the rows the remainder of the row count and 2 will switch between 0 and 1. For each column we want the opposite. If you add the row count to the column count and get the remainder we get the desired result. Example `(r + c)` will give `(0 + 0) % 2 == 0`, `(1 + 0) % 2 == 1`, `(2 + 0) % 2 == 0`, `(3 + 0) % 2 == 1`, then the next column `(0 + 1) % 2 == 1`, `(1 + 1) % 2 == 0`, `(2 + 1) % 2 == 1`, `(3 + 1) % 2 == 0`. and so on.

The `%` operator has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the [addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) operator [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) thus we need to put the [grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) operators [`(`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) [`)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) around the addition.

Eg `3 + 1 % 2` will equal 4. The `1 % 2` is done first then the 3 is added while `(3 + 1) % 2` will equal 0. The `(3 + 1)` is first then the remainder is done

### The [Ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator

We can do this most simply using the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator [`?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). eg `color = (c + r) % 2 ? "white" : "black"` which is the same as `if ((c + r) % 2 === 1) { color = "white" } else { color = "black" }`

### Example

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const tileW = 20;
const tileH = 20;
const tileRowCount = 25;
const tileColCount = 40;
const tiles = [];

for (let c = 0; c < tileColCount; c++) {
    for (let r = 0; r < tileRowCount; r++) {
        tiles.push({
            x: c * (tileW + 3),
            y: r * (tileH + 3),
            color: (c + r) % 2 ? "white" : "black",
        });
    }
}
for (const tile of tiles) {
    ctx.fillStyle = tile.color;
    ctx.fillRect(tile.x, tile.y, tileW, tileH);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width='1000' height='600'></canvas>
```